# AFNetworking: "Remote server closed the connection before sending response header" but successblock is called

Tags: ios, afnetworking, http-proxy

I'm just debugging an error some of my customers experience, now I stumbled upon a weird behavior: according to charles proxy, a request failed ("Remote server closed the connection before sending response header") but my success block was called.

Is this a known behavior/issue?